# HSQLDB - how to set .lobs file encoding?

Tags: hsqldb

We run a little java web application on a hsqldb 2.4 database, and apparently the encoding of the .lobs file where blobs are persisted depends on the OS holding it. For instance, it is encoded in Ansi when the application runs on windows, which is problematic when we want to send on a Linux system (via http) the files represented by its blobs.

Do anyone know how to specify the encoding of this .lobs file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HSQLDB does not encode the data in blobs. It stores the data exactly as inserted. If you need to encode the files represented by the blobs in a different character set, you have to do it in your application.